# Why do dynamic libraries on macOS have an id?

Tags: macos, linker, dylib, dynamic-library, otool

Can anyone explain why dynamic libraries on macOS have an id, and it's always a path? I can change this `id` via `install_name_tool` but why is this even necessary?

I don't recall this on Linux. Why did Apple decide to not pass the path of the loaded path during initialization?

```
$ otool -L /path/to/lib/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib
/path/to/lib:
    @loader_path/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib <--- ??? (compatibility ...)
    .. other dependencies
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because "standard paths" just aren't enough for macOS.

On Linux, libraries are identified by `$(basename $path)` and everything is thrown in `/usr/lib` or some other standard path. If two libraries collide, that's your problem. If you don't have root permissions, that's your problem. If you wanna test some stuff, you can at least set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but for distribution that's really not great.

Now consider macOS (and by extension, iOS) where /usr/lib is on a readonly volume and applications very often ship third-party frameworks inside their .app bundle, and expect them to work regardless of path on disk, and without requiring root to install.

Shared libraries on macOS have an ID that is a path, because that path tells the runtime linker where to find the library on disk.
Now you might ask why doesn't it just embed the compile-time path of the library? For one, because entire app bundles might get moved around, and for another, because cross-compilation is a thing.

In essence, this gives the same capability as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, except with the granularity of single binaries, and in a way that can be distributed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation!